# How to use groupby on expanding windows with Pandas/Numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

The dataframe example. The last column might have NaNs.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
nb_rows=100
# Creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(nb_rows,3), index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=nb_rows, freq='D'), columns=['group1', 'group2', 'measure1'])
# Adding NaNs in the last column
df['measure1'][df['measure1']>0.85] = np.nan
```

I want to use an expanding window, discretize and groupby column `group1` and `group2` for each expansion, and then apply some function. I'm currently doing it this way:

```
# Function for creating the list of window slices
def exp_windows(x, min_periods):
    return [x[:i] for i in range(min_periods, x.shape[0] + 1)]

# Function for performing the discretization, grouping, and the apply
def do_grouping(win):
  nparray = np.column_stack((pd.qcut(win[:, 0], q=10, labels=False), pd.qcut(win[:, 1], q=10, labels=False), win[:, 2]))
  df = pd.DataFrame(nparray, columns=['group1', 'group2', 'measure1'])
  return df.groupby(['group1', 'group2'])['measure1'].describe()

list_windows = exp_windows(df.values, 7)
[do_grouping(win) for win in list_windows]
```

I replaced the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function by a simple call to the [describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) function. I would like to know how this problem could be realized by using the Pandas [expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) function. When I tried applying the `groupby` function to the `expanding` function, I got the following error (hence why I tried another approach).

```
AttributeError: 'Expanding' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

As requested in a comment, here the first two groupby generated by the do_grouping() function:

```
[               count      mean  std  ...       50%       75%       max
 group1 group2                        ...                              
 0.0    0.0       1.0  0.832620  NaN  ...  0.832620  0.832620  0.832620
 1.0    4.0       1.0  0.528895  NaN  ...  0.528895  0.528895  0.528895
 3.0    8.0       0.0       NaN  NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
 4.0    1.0       1.0  0.645894  NaN  ...  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894
 6.0    3.0       1.0  0.602763  NaN  ...  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763
 8.0    9.0       1.0  0.071036  NaN  ...  0.071036  0.071036  0.071036
 9.0    6.0       0.0       NaN  NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
 
 [7 rows x 8 columns],
                count      mean  std  ...       50%       75%       max
 group1 group2                        ...                              
 0.0    0.0       1.0  0.832620  NaN  ...  0.832620  0.832620  0.832620
 1.0    5.0       1.0  0.528895  NaN  ...  0.528895  0.528895  0.528895
 2.0    8.0       0.0       NaN  NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
 4.0    1.0       1.0  0.645894  NaN  ...  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894
 5.0    4.0       1.0  0.602763  NaN  ...  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763
 7.0    9.0       1.0  0.071036  NaN  ...  0.071036  0.071036  0.071036
 8.0    7.0       0.0       NaN  NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
 9.0    2.0       1.0  0.780529  NaN  ...  0.780529  0.780529  0.780529
 
 [8 rows x 8 columns],
```

Comment: Hi @m_power, cna you gve an example of your desired output ? I’m not sure what it would look like to combine expand + groupby

Comment: @Cimbali Currently, it is a list of the grouby results. The describe result is not small, hence why I didn't add it to the question. I'll add an example of the first groupby included in the list.

Comment: `expanding().(...)` wants to return a dataframe, not a list, so it’s kind of hard to imagine how we could get there.

Comment: @Cimbali, it could definitely be replaced by a single dataframe as output. Maybe the main index could be the window slice index.

Answer (score 0):

it seems this can’t be done with `expanding` − any expanding transformation function expects a single value as return, whereas you want to return a full dataframe (groups as indexes, stats as columns).

We can probably simplify what you did a little bit, but we’ll still end up with a list comprehension.

First generate window sizes:

```
>>> window_size = df.notna().cumsum().min(axis='columns')
>>> window_size
2021-01-01     1
2021-01-02     2
2021-01-03     2
2021-01-04     3
2021-01-05     4
              ..
2021-04-06    80
2021-04-07    81
2021-04-08    82
2021-04-09    83
2021-04-10    83
Freq: D, Length: 100, dtype: int64
```

Then with a list comprehension we can iterate on indexes and apply the function you want:

```
>>> pd.concat({index: df.loc[:index].groupby(['group1', 'group2']).describe()
... for index, size in window_size.iteritems() if size >= 2})
                             measure1                                                                
                                count      mean std       min       25%       50%       75%       max
           group1   group2                                                                           
2021-01-02 0.544883 0.423655      1.0  0.645894 NaN  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894
           0.548814 0.715189      1.0  0.602763 NaN  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763
2021-01-03 0.437587 0.891773      0.0       NaN NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
           0.544883 0.423655      1.0  0.645894 NaN  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894
           0.548814 0.715189      1.0  0.602763 NaN  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763
2021-01-04 0.383442 0.791725      1.0  0.528895 NaN  0.528895  0.528895  0.528895  0.528895  0.528895
           0.437587 0.891773      0.0       NaN NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
           0.544883 0.423655      1.0  0.645894 NaN  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894
           0.548814 0.715189      1.0  0.602763 NaN  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763
2021-01-05 0.383442 0.791725      1.0  0.528895 NaN  0.528895  0.528895  0.528895  0.528895  0.528895
           0.437587 0.891773      0.0       NaN NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
           0.544883 0.423655      1.0  0.645894 NaN  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894  0.645894
           0.548814 0.715189      1.0  0.602763 NaN  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763  0.602763
           0.568045 0.925597      1.0  0.071036 NaN  0.071036  0.071036  0.071036  0.071036  0.071036
```

Here I made a limit on `size >= 2` for a smaller example, but you can set it to any value you want.

Comment: I'll test that, it seems similar to my approach. However, I'm looking for a solution with the Pandas expanding window function.

Comment: @m_power Returning anything else than a scalar value from `.expanding` throws an error, so you can't do groupbys.

Comment: I was checking something, could it work by doing a `groupby` in an `.apply`, e.g. `df.expanding(...).apply(lambda x: groupby(...))`?

Comment: I'm getting slight differences in the results (discretized groups are not the same) with your solution. I don't know yet what might cause this.